# Clean install of OS X Lion from USB "can't download the additional components"

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion

I've created a bootable Lion USB with [Lion Disk Maker](http://blog.gete.net/lion-diskmaker-us/) using a 4GB Flash drive. I'm trying to perform a clean install on my MacBook Pro which previously has Snow Leopard on it.

I insert the flash drive and boot from it. Then I go to Disk Utility and erase all partitions and format it with HFS+ Journaled. Then I choose the second option to install OS X.

At the very beginning of the installation I receive a popup

> Can't download the additional components needed to install Mac OS X.

So I connect to WiFi and try again. This time I get:

> The additional components needed to install Mac OS X can't be found.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what happen. Its seem that the 4GB flash drive option isn't working. I've manage to find an 8GB flash drive and try again. This time no problem!.